# How to scrape inside <div> list using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am looking for a way to efficiently scrape information formatted in the following way using **puppeteer.**
Suppose I have a list of things on a website divided as such:

```
<div id="list">
  <div class="item" pos="0"> 
  <a href="www.somewebsite.com">
    <div class="nameToRetrieve"> Name 1 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" pos="1"> 
  <a href="www.somewebsite.com">
    <div class="nameToRetrieve"> Name 2 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" pos="2"> 
  <a href="www.somewebsite.com">
    <div class="nameToRetrieve"> Name 3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I retrieve the information of the names (Name 1, Name 2 and Name 3?

I have tried fitting them into an object to make then into an array, but I am still confused as to how to approach it.

```
const listOfStuff = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByClassName('itemResult')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special convenience method [`page.$$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) for this task in puppeteer:

```
let result = await page.$$eval('.nameToRetrieve', names => names.map(name => name.textContent));
console.log(result);
```

> This method runs Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)) within the page and passes it as the first argument to pageFunction.

The result will be:

`[ ' Name 1 ', ' Name 2 ', ' Name 3 ' ]`

Answer (score 2):

Not much to do with the `puppeteer` API I think. On modern browsers (ES6) converting to an array is elegant, and then just map it. Note I assumed `nameToRetrieve` only appears in stuff you want to retrieve, so no need to get the `"list"`.

```js
var names = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("nameToRetrieve")).map(x => x.innerHTML);
console.log(names)
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="item" pos="0"> 
  <a href="www.somewebsite.com">
    <div class="nameToRetrieve"> Name 1 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" pos="1"> 
  <a href="www.somewebsite.com">
    <div class="nameToRetrieve"> Name 2 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" pos="2"> 
  <a href="www.somewebsite.com">
    <div class="nameToRetrieve"> Name 3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```